# hide a class except a specific class inside it

Tags: jquery

i have the following divs:

```
<div id="hidethis">
    <!-- here i have some more divs, each with a classqid name -->
    <div class="donthide">
    </div>     
</div>
```

i want to hide everything inside the surounding div `#hidethis"` except the div `".donthide"`.
i read some related posts and i tried:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hidethis").not(".donthide").hide();
 });
```

or this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#hidethis").filter(".donthide").hide();
 });
```

but nothing seems to work, it hides everything including ".donthide"

thanks to all helpers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
$("#hidethis").children(":not(.donthide)").hide();
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/FveKc/

Comment: works. if inside the dic i also had some <a> or <p> they would also be considered as his children? or only the nested <div>s are his children?

Comment: `children` only gets the *direct* descendants of the selected elements. In other words, anything underneath `.donthide` will be preserved. **Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/TQLrJ/

Answer (score 1):

This selector can work with CSS3 as well (you don't even need jQuery):

```
$('#hidethis > :not(.donthide)').hide();
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mn7DV/5/**

And the CSS3 equivalent :

```
#hidethis > :not(.donthide) { 
  display: none;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/V7xew/1/**

Comment: Hmm, I think children underneath `.donthide` will still be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You were close with your first example: you need to specify that you are hiding all of the children of the parent div except for the .donthide one, like this:

```
$('#parentDiv').children(':not(.dontHide)').hide();
```

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5fN9B/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":not(.donthide)", $("#hidethis")).hide();
```

I like to use the context-- but this is similar to other replies.